# Do I need to update bind-related packages if I use rpcbind?

Tags: centos, upgrade, bind

I'm being told I need to update `bind-export-libs`, `bind-libs`, `bind-libs-lite`, `bind-license` and `bind-utils` but my server doesn't use Bind or Bind9, it uses `rcpbind`.

So, do I have to actually update these or are they just if you use Bind or Bind9 for DNS?

I'm on CentOS 7 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've just done a `yum deplist rpcbind`, and none of the above `bind` utilities are mentioned so I guess they they don't need updating after all.